# Index problems in subtraction within a for loop

Tags: r

I am trying to figure out the mistake in my code as I am trying to do subtraction of row by next row using for loop

```
aa <- for(i in 1:nrow(df)) {
    df$subset <- df$AMZN[(i + 1)] - df$AMZN[(i)]
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set the index `[i]` on the left hand side:

```
data(iris)

df <- iris
aa<-for(i in 1:nrow(df)){
  df$subset[i] <-df$Sepal.Length[(i+1)]-df$Sepal.Length[(i)]
}
```

There are also better ways of doing this than using a `for` loop, but I am limiting my answer to the scope of the question you asked.